# Calculate Moving Range using tidyverse

Tags: r, sliding-window

I would like to know the moving range value of the Pay variable in the Df dataset below:
Moving Range defined as maximum of current and previous value minus minimum of current and previous value.

```
library(tidyverse)

Df <- structure(list(
  Venture = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "R", "R", "R", "R", "S", "S", "S", "S"), 
  Type = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
  Section = c("Sect111", "Sect111", "Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect113", "Sect113", "Sect114", "Sect114", "Sect115", "Sect115", "Sect116", "Sect116"), 
  Pay = c(102029, 102271, 679263, 669249, 203499, 218765, 495000, 487562, 773432, 765423, 233345, 245690)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

df2 <- data.frame(Df)

df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(Venture, Section) %>%
  distinct(Type,.keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(MR = if(length(Pay) > 1){
        map_dbl(2:length(Pay), 
                   ~max(Pay[.x], 
                        Pay[.x-1]) - min(Pay[.x],
                                         Pay[.x-1]))
         } else {
           NA_real_
         }
  )
```

**Error:** All of the MR values generated by the code above is NA instead of absolute difference of current value minus the previous value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `zoo::rollapplyr` is a good fit for this.

```r
Df %>%
  group_by(Venture, Section) %>%
  mutate(moving_range = zoo::rollapplyr(Pay, 2, fill = NA, FUN = function(z) diff(range(z)))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 × 5
#    Venture  Type Section    Pay moving_range
#    <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1 N           1 Sect111 102029           NA
#  2 N           1 Sect111 102271          242
#  3 N           2 Sect112 679263           NA
#  4 N           2 Sect112 669249        10014
#  5 R           1 Sect113 203499           NA
#  6 R           1 Sect113 218765        15266
#  7 R           2 Sect114 495000           NA
#  8 R           2 Sect114 487562         7438
#  9 S           1 Sect115 773432           NA
# 10 S           1 Sect115 765423         8009
# 11 S           2 Sect116 233345           NA
# 12 S           2 Sect116 245690        12345
```

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans for prompt response. I am getting an error, moving range must be size 1, not 0

Comment: it works with this data, what in your real data is different?

Comment: I am using the distinct statement in between group_by and mutate, as I would like to drop all those rows which are duplicates by type variable before calculating moving range for the pay variable. ``` df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(Venture, Section) %>%
  distinct(Type,.keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(moving_range = zoo::rollapplyr(Pay, 2, fill = NA, FUN = function(z) diff(range(z)))) %>%
  ungroup()```